# NameError: name 'testing' is not defined in vscode

Tags: python

this is my code

```
import pygame, sys 
from pygame.locals import *
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model
import cv2


WINDOWSIZEX = 640 
WINDOWSIZEY = 480

BOUNDARYINC = 5
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0 ,0)
RED = (255, 0 , 0 )

IMAGESAVE = False

MODEL = load_model("bestmodel.h5")
PREDICT = True
LABELS = {0:"Zero", 1:"One",
        2:"Two", 3:"Three",
        4:"Four", 5:"Five",
        6:"Six", 7:"Seven",
        8:"eEight", 9:"Nine"}

pygame.init()

FONT = pygame.font.Font("FreeSansBold.ttf", 18)


DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWSIZEX, WINDOWSIZEY))

pygame.display.set_caption("Digit Boaard")

iswriting = False

number_xcord = []
number_ycord = []

image_cnt = 1


while True:

    for  event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == MOUSEMOTION and iswriting:     
            xcord, ycord = event.pos
            pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, (xcord,ycord), 4, 0 )

            number_xcord.append(xcord)
            number_ycord.append(ycord)

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            iswriting = True

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            iswriting = False
            number_xcord = sorted(number_xcord)
            number_ycord = sorted(number_ycord)

            rect_min_x , rect_max_x = max(number_xcord[0]-BOUNDARYINC, 0 ), min(WINDOWSIZEX, number_xcord[-1]+BOUNDARYINC)
            rect_min_Y , rect_max_Y = max(number_ycord[0]-BOUNDARYINC, 0 ), min(number_ycord[-1]+BOUNDARYINC, WINDOWSIZEX) 

            number_xcord = []
            number_ycord = []

            img_arr = np.array(pygame.PixelArray(DISPLAYSURF))[rect_min_x:rect_max_x, rect_min_Y:rect_max_Y].T.astype(np.float32)

            if IMAGESAVE:
                cv2.imwrite("image.png")
                image_cnt +=1

            if PREDICT:

                image = cv2.resize(img_arr, (28,28))
                image = np.pad(image, (10,10), 'constant', constant_values = 0 )
                image = cv2.resize(image, (28,28))/255

                label = str(LABELS[np.argmax(MODEL.predict(image.reshape(1,28,28,1)))])

                textSurface = FONT.render(label, True, RED, WHITE)
                textRecObj = testing.get_rect()
                textRecObj.left , textRecObj.bottom = rect_min_x, rect_max_Y

                DISPLAYSURF.blit(textSurface, textRecObj)

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.unicode == "n":
                    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BLACK)


        pygame.display.update()
```

and this is the error i've been getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\dell\app.py", line 86, in <module>
    textRecObj = testing.get_rect()
NameError: name 'testing' is not defined
```

im taking a course in university on "Data science" and this the required project
my lecturer gave us only one week to build a Handwritten Digit Recognition model. i only started taking this course 3 weeks ago so im not really familiar with the subject...
i followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2cAjgc1-bo&lc=Ugy5PxPjcqMIrl93iNR4AaABAg&ab_channel=edureka%21
can you help me?

Comment: It says `testing` isn't defined and tells you where you used `testing` as a variable. What is supposed to be there? is it a typo?

Answer (score 2):

You've never defined what `testing` is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the line is supposed to be

```
textRecObj = textSurface.get_rect()
```

Seems you accidentally made a typo.

Comment: it worked!! thank you